# Suppose m, n ∈ N. Explain why n|m implies n ≤ m.

Tags: divisibility, natural-numbers

I know that, by definition, *n*|*m* implies *m*=*pn* for which *p* is an integer, but I don't know how to get *n* ≤ *m*.

Comment: Suppose $m < n$.  Then derive a contradiction from that.

Comment: Well, can $p$ be negative?

Comment: Yes, because p is an integer.

Comment: $m \neq pn$ if p is a negative number, since both m, n are positive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is positive, just note that $k\cdot n \ge n$ for positive integers $k$. (That's just saying that "Multiplying by a number by something bigger than one makes it bigger.")

Of course it breaks if you allow $n$ to divide $-n$, for example.

Comment: Only _m_ and _n_ are positive, but _p_ can't be 0.

Comment: John, if p is a negative number, and both m, n are positive, then $m \neq pn$: i.e., you get a contradiction.  If p is negative, and n is positive, then $m = pn <0$.